# Assistance with parallel.foreach

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have the following piece of code that I'm trying to convert to ***parallel.foreach***, and haven't had any luck. I'm basically trying to speed this part of my program up and want to run the for loop in parallel.

```
arrComputers = Split(currentrow(0), vbCrLf)
 For Each strComputer In arrComputers
  do stuff
  do stuff
  n = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
  OtherSub(n, strComputer)
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Exaple2 of this is what you are looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71285/Introducing-NET-Parallel-Programming

Answer (score 0):

It might not be quite as simple as just running in parallel, UI elements usually all like to work on one thread, so you might want to break that out.

Assuming everything works in parallel your loop would look like

```
Parallel.ForEach(arrComputers, Sub(strComputer )
                                 do stuff
                                 do stuff
                                 n = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                                 OtherSub(n, strComputer)
                                 end sub())
```

Though ive taken to using

```
Dim Tasks as list(of task)
For Each strComputer In arrComputers
   tasks.add(task.run(sub() 
       do stuff
       do stuff
       n = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
       OtherSub(n, strComputer)
   End Sub())
Next
do OtherStuff
do OtherStuff
Task.waitall(tasks.toarray)
```

I find it more flexible I can mix thing that need to be done synchronously with things that can be done in parallel also it extends far more cleanly to the async model in Net 4.5 where task.waitall can be changed for task await task.whenall, and I can achieve async and in parallel if needed.
Also if there is lots of code in your lambda you can stick it in a sub for readability.
Tim

Comment: I am getting Run (for task.run) is not a member of system.threading.tasks.task and toarray(for task.toarray) is not a member of tasks.

Comment: I tried your first method as well and was getting a "AmbiguousMatchException" error.